# py2exe ImportError: no module named <package I have impemented>

Tags: python, eclipse, py2exe, distutils

I have implemented a package names myUtils, it consists of folder 'myUtils', file '**init**.py' and a number of *.py files with names != 'myUtils'. This package is included in myOtherProject.py and can be found/used when I run them from Eclipse.

However, when I run py2exe on myOtherProject.py, resulting exe cannot find this module(error message "ImportError: no module named myUtils"). Trimmed version of my setup.exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys
sys.path.append(pathTo_myUtils)
import myUtils # this line works fine even if I comment out sys.path.append(...)
data_files_ = (('.', ["C:\\Python27\\DLLs\\MSVCP90.dll", 
                      "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin\\mfc90.dll"]))
setup(windows=['myOtherProject.py'], options={'py2exe': {'excludes': ['tcl'], 'includes': ['myUtils'], 'dll_excludes': ['tk85.dll',  'tcl85.dll'] }}, data_files=data_files_)
```

How could I fix this? I am using Python 2.7 on WinXP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not define PYTHONPATH properly; there were spaces after semicolons. Instead of

```
c:\aa\; c:\bb\; c:\cc\
```

it needed to be

```
c:\aa;c:\bb;c:\cc
```

For packages that are defined using **init**.py (package MyPackage corresponds to a folder MyPackage, that contains **init**.py and some other files, without MyPackage.py), path that I needed to add to PYTHONPATH was not

```
<path_to_MyPackage>\MyPackage
```

but just

```
<path_to_MyPackage>
```

...

Comment: I had this issue because I was trying to use relative imports (to other modules in the same package). You're solution worked but for some reason I couldn't specify a different 'script' path option, the py2exe script had to be located where the main script for the software was located.

Answer (score 2):

put your `sys.path.append()` line BEFORE the `import` statement. Better yet, modify your PYTHONPATH (i'm not sure how to do this on windows, but i'm sure Google can tell you how)

Comment: Sorry in real setup.py it is before the import, and import would work even if I comment out sys.path.append(pathTo_myUtils). Will edit to eliminate confusion.